# Unable to share component between two pages angular ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, angular2-template, angular-components

I want to share component between two pages in ionic 3.

I have common component `SearchInputComponent` added in component folder.

When i try to add, i was getting this error **SearchInputComponent is part of the declarations of 2 modules**

After searching a bit on net i found a way i.e create new sharedModule inside it keep common components.

So created `SharedModule.module.ts` in component folder.

**SharedModule.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { SearchInputComponent } from './search-input/search-input';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
     ],
    declarations: [
        SearchInputComponent
    ],
    exports: [
        SearchInputComponent
    ]
})

export class SharedModule {}
```

I want to use my `SearchInputComponent` in myPage1 and myPage2,

so inside

**myPage1.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    myPage1
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(myPage1),
    SharedModule
  ],
})
export class myPage1PageModule {}
```

**myPage2.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    myPage2
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(myPage2),
    SharedModule
  ],
})
export class myPage2PageModule {}
```

but it is not working, showing some weird `Error: Template parse errors:....`

Can any one help me to find my mistake?

***Thank you in advance!***

Comment: the error looks like be in your HTML template .. post it .. cause i think you've a typo there ..and post ALL the error

Comment: why not import SharedModule in app-main.module?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please write all the error log?
It seems that you have exported and imported right the module. But maybe there is an error with the template.

For discarding template errors, try to comment all the logic on your 'SearchInputComponent'.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, It might help someone

**SharedModule.module.ts**

I added 
`imports: [IonicPageModule.forChild(SearchInputComponent)],` and it got worked.